# how to load all matching data row for selected dropdown values ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

i have dropdown boxes for user_id and er and once both selected i want to load all the data as rows.  please advice.

below is my controller

`$getShifts = Shifts::Where('user_id','=',$user_id)->Where('week_id','=',$week)->get();`

how can i proceed

table

```
   <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <tr class="table-header">
                                        <th>Day</th>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Start</th>
                                        <th>End</th>
                                        <th>Total
                                            <br/> Hours
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Run
                                            <br/> Type
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Edit
                                            <br/> / Delete
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
```

EDIT 
plese check below code which i have tried

```
               success: function(data) {
                    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);//parse JSON

                    var output="<tr>";
                    for (var i in json_obj)
                    {

                        output+=
                                "<td>" +  json_obj[i].id + "</td>"+
                                "<td>" +  json_obj[i].bus_no + "</td>"+
                                "<td>" +  json_obj[i].shift_no + "</td>"

                        ;

                    }
                    output+="</tr>";

                    $('#span').html(output);

                }
```

Comment: You can use `Ajax` and pass the values selected to a url like `http://somewebsite.com` (either by POST or GET). Return the rows by formatting it as either `JSON or XML` and use `JQuery` to parse it and display it here.

Comment: You need to use ajax. The provided code doesn't really helpful here for us to answer your question. You have to provide us the javascript code you used to display the rows.

Comment: @user3571366 im using html table for display data. i have updated my question with table columns , can i do the same using javscript as well . please advice

Comment: I assume you get the response properly from your server? Now I see you're appending the output into an element #span. But do you have a #span element in your page? That's why you don't get the output. and also, the way you've looped over the result also incorrect. There are 7 <th> elements, but you only create 3 <td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your controller function in ajax and in controller you will get the selected data, so based on that run required query.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#combo, #user_id").change(function(){

       var combo = $('#combo option:selected').val();    
       var user_id = $('#user_id option:selected').val();   
       if(combo && user_id) { 
            $.ajax({
                url: "path to controller function",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "HTML",
                async: false,
                data:{combo:combo.user_id:user_id},
                success: function(data) {
                      alert(data)   // here you ll see the data from controllen, you can manipulate according to your requirement.               
                }
          }); 
        }

     });
});
```

in controller

```
echo "
   <tr>
       <td>$day</td>
       <td>$date</td>
       <td>$start</td>
       <td>$end</td>
       <td>$end</td>
       <td>$end</td>
   </tr>  ";
```

manipulate all fields in to a `tr` in controller and in ajax `success()` append the data to table.

Comment: thanks it works, how can i display those date in a table. i have updated my question with required table columns. pls advice

Comment: are you able to get required values in controller??

Comment: yes , im getting all required values, i want to know how to display it on my view

Comment: have tried using success , but table is not generating correctly. im getting only one record, even controller out puts many. please advice
kindly check updated question "EDIT section"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92004/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-faz-faz).